# How to build a material for an alligator watch strap?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I'm trying to learn how to build more complex materials for cycles. For a watch model I've made I would like to have leather alligator-style straps, like these:

[image]

Not sure how I would attack this. Have a pattern for the bigger patches, and use as a bump/displacement map, plus as a mask for smaller streaks/scratches?

Comment: Main problem/challenge here is that it's really hard to create such irregular pattern in Cycles. Google a bit for 'cycles irregular bricks' or something similar and you will see many threads started but not solved. This is better example of what you need, I think: https://previews.123rf.com/images/soesoe/soesoe0607/soesoe060700084/465906-Croco-Leather-Texture-Stock-Photo.jpg

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44880/multiple-texture-displacements-mapping-in-one-scene/44927#44927 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77649/crumpled-paper-cycles-texture/77652#77652 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28942/methods-of-applying-bumpiness-to-materials/29041#29041