# Turn cycles normal map into geometry displacement?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking, displacement

How can I convert a Cycles procedural texture displacement (which is just a normal/bump mapping) into geometry displacement?

---

[image: cycles generated bump map]

I am aware that I could use the above image as a texture for the displacement. This is not ideal as it is affected by the lighting.

---

[image: rendered result]

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/31696/599. For clarity, is this a cycles procedural texture you wish to use for displacement? Or an image texture?

Comment: Procedural texture.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the displacement modifier to do this, just remember that you have to subdivide the model to get more geometry to displace.

[image]

If you want to use a procedural texture you can do it changing the texture in the modifier

Also you can use cycles displacement but this is an experimental feature

Comment: The displacement modifier does not work with procedural textures generated in cycles.

Comment: Render the image on a plane first looking at it with an ortho camera, then save that image, and load it up into the Modifier shown.

Comment: Not directly, but some cycles procedural textures are the same that the Blender Internal procedural textures, so you can use BI textures with the same values of the cycles texutres

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that you cant use the rendered image because it is affected by the lighting,TO remove all the lighting information just plug the displacement texture into the color of an emission shader and render the image,it will just be as the one you would plug into the displacement out put and you can use it as a texture to displace the geometry.