# Apply vector mapping to displace texture?

Tags: texturing, uv

I am using this method for my object texturing and displacement of my mesh.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W07H7xeUnGE

If you haven't seen this tutorial, the final node tree looks like this

[image]

In addition to this node tree, I am also using a Texture Coordinate node and a vector mapping node and have changed the values so my textures fit properly. The issue I am having is I can not figure out how to, or if it's possible, to also apply that same vector mapping to the displace texture.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Could you show your node setup? What do you mean by "deform texture"? Each image texture node has its own Vector mapping input that can be feeded with the same vector field, isn't that working?

Comment: I am using deform in the modifiers tab. In other words, there is no deform in my node tree.

Comment: I just realized I mean a displace modifier, not deform

Comment: Currently (2.77) node based texture for feeding the displacement are not supported (see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31696/using-texture-nodes-for-the-displace-modifier?rq=1), so you'll have to ensure the match in another way. What kind of mapping are you using for your textures? And for the displace texture?

Answer (score 1):

I had a run in with this problem and I solved it by applying that displacement texture I want to an emission shader on the object I want displaced. I baked the mapped texture and then used that one as the displacement map.