# How to edit a glass shader to make it look like bumpy frosted glass

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I was wondering if any of you had any ideas on how I might setup a shader to look something like this (in Cycles):

[image]

It's a little bit frosted, but the main thing that I'm trying to acheive is the "bumpy" appearence.  Thanks!

Comment: i think this effect is called "Etched Glass"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can also use a [*bump node*](http://blender.org/manual/render/cycles/nodes/more.html#bump), which offers more control and tends to have fewer artifacts than the displacement output (see [What is the difference between the displace socket and a bump map?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14351/599)):

[image]

<sub>The fake glass node group lets light pass through the glass more easily, see [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2565/599).</sub>

Answer (score 9):

Just set up the nodes as pictured below.
[image]

Add a ***Noise Texture*** node (*<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>-->Texture-->Noise Texture*) and play with its settings. Connect it to the *Displacement* socket of the *Material Output* node. Place a ***Math Node*** (*<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>-->Converter-->Math*) between them and set its type to *Multiply* to control the amount of the bumpiness.
[image]

You may also increase the ***Roughness*** value of the *Glass Node*. I think you may not need to add a bumpiness then. Of course you can try to increase the Roughness value and add the bumpiness at the same time.
[image]