# How can I achieve this glass look?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency, glass, solidify-modifier

So Im currently remaking a set of icons on Blender ( the originals were apparently made in C4D ) and I'm having trouble recreating the exact look they have. I'm attaching a screen of the original with two comparisons ( the 2nd & 3rd one are mine ) ,as well as the node setup I'm currently using for the glass. It needs to be greenish in color, grainy as the one from C4D. The middle comparison also has a Solidify Mod added to it.[image]

[image]

[image]
Im also using the "Transparent Glass" setting from Blender with a value of 1.
I'm adding the .blend file as a [link](https://we.tl/t-7PTRzKY88q) from WeTransfer since I can't upload it on Blend-Exchange for some reason. I feel like this should be fairly simple thing to redo in Blender but I can't seem to get the grain right and the glass itself is too grey when using the Noise Node so maybe there's another way to redo the whole thing.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32022/how-to-edit-a-glass-shader-to-make-it-look-like-bumpy-frosted-glass https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/143905/making-a-wall-made-from-glass-bricks

Answer (score 2):

I think the main parameters you need to tweak are the *Base Color* (it needs to be between white and gre), the *Roughness*, the *IOR*. Here instead of a *Displacement* node I've plugged a *Noise Texture* into a *Bump* node, but the result should be about the same.

[image]

For the third one I've mixed the *Principled BSDF* with a *Diffuse* put kept the *Mix Shader* rather low:

[image]