# A shape with Particle effects changes size after being temporarily masked in the Outliner

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, particles, outliner

First I created a circle and applied a Particle System to create pine cone style vegetation.

Then I masked the Circle in the Outliner (using the Eye icon), to allow Blender to go faster, and created a little house with a smokey chimney (smoke made with Metaballs) to place in the scene. I converted the Metaballs to Mesh and applied a decimate to it.

Only, when I clicked on the Circle's Eye icon again in the outliner, the Circle was now huge and had undergone a transformation I didn't expect.

[image]
*Looks small in material view, huge in rendered view. But it used to look small in rendered view too in the beginning*.

The only modifier is the one on the smoke (displace), so I thought that was accidentally applied to the Circle, but I can't see this modifier listed when I select the Circle.

What happened to this Object, and how do I make it look "normal" again in Rendered view?

[image]

Comment: The only thing I can think of that would change the geometry in rendered view would be the experimental [Cycles true displacement](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15478/5705).

Comment: ok... thanks. There are no images or textures, only a particle system and simple diffuse or glas materials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your particles are huge.

[image]

Try using something like `.01` for the root size (this value is in BU, at least when *Scaling* is set to 1).

Comment: Ok! That's the answer. For a strange reason, I feel that the info for "root size" got corrupted and changed when I made/modified the house or when I hid that object and unhid it... very strange. Thanks a lot!

Comment: (and thanks for saying my particles are huge)